# First attempt at a MySQLi Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to re-write some mysqli queries as prepared statements (my first attempt at this). The first two commented lines are the old query that worked just fine. The remainder is my attempt to write a prepared statement:

```
//$sql = "SELECT hashed_password FROM Administrators WHERE user_name='$username'";
//$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

//switch to prepared statement
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
$result = false;
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 
    'SELECT hashed_password FROM Administrators WHERE user_name=?')) 
{

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

    /* execute query */
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    //mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

if (!$result) {
    mysqli_close($link);
    die("Error running query " . mysqli_error($link));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        mysqli_close($link);
        echo "No such user";
        die();
    }
```

The error occurs is revealed in the last line, but obviously traces back to one of the earlier lines.

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? I took this directly from the PHP docs, but I'm missing something, obviously. Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks to people who pointed out that I forgot to assign the return value from the query. I've incorporated those comments and modified my code. However, I'm still not able to successfully run the query. Now I get this error:

`Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/07/11347607/html/RevRunning/scripts/administration/login.php on line 53
No such user`

Trust me, the user that I've entered in the UI does exist, so something is still wrong with my code. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: you have `if (!$result)` and since you never set `$result`, it will always call the `die(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, it looks like I had a couple of problems.

First, this is wrong:

```
/* execute query */
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

There is a command for binding the results to a variable. The correct approach is this:

```
/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* Bind results to variable */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
```

My other problem was in interpreting the return value (i.e. what is stored in `$result`). When I was using non-prepared statements, the return value was a dataset that I needed to unwrap by first using `mysqli_fetch_array($result)`. I could test the number of rows in this dataset with `mysqli_num_rows`. In this situation at least, the return value was just a single string, but I still had to unwrap it with `mysqli_fetch_array`.

Not with prepared statements, though. The return value now is simply a string, so all I need to do to test if I got something back is something like this:

```
if (!stmt) { // do before closing $stmt
    mysqli_close($link);
    echo "Query Error";
    die();
}
```

and

```
if (!$result) {
    mysqli_close($link);
    echo "No results returned";
    die();
}
```

This is just based on my own testing and finding a successful solution. If I stated anything incorrectly or if anyone can give a better answer, please feel free to comment.

Thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: You would saved yourself a lot of trouble if browsed some related questions. You're not only one who is trying prepared statements for the first time, you know.

Answer (score 1):

In order to test if the query failed you will need to get the return boolean from `mysqli_stmt_execute` like this:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

then you will be able to check:

```
if (!$result) {
 // if you get here it mean $result is false
 //therefore it failed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't notice that. I'm still having troubles and have updated my post.

Comment: @usr55410 That error normally means that the query that was last executed has failed. Echo your query and try it direct against the database. Are the field and table names used in the query correct?

Comment: Thanks. I realize that the query failed. That's why I posted the two commented lines where you can see the old query that works. If the old query works, and the parameters are exactly the same, then the problem has to be somewhere in the new code (I assume). Do you agree?

Comment: yes I agree it means the issue is the code try merging both condtions `if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)`

Comment: @usr55410 you can also get the count like this `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;`

Answer (score 0):

You get this `Couldn't fetch mysqli` error because you are accessing an object that you have already closed.

As you can see here...

```
   /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  //<-------- As you have closed it !!!!
}

if (!$result) {    //<------ But you are accessing it here !
    mysqli_close($link);
    die("Error running query " . mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried taking that `mysqli_stmt_close` line out (see the edits to my post), but I'm still having similar results.

Comment: But the `$result` variable is not declared anywhere , so it will definitely go inside the  `if` statement as as you have done `!$result`

Comment: Thank you, but look more closely. `$result = false;` is the second line of code.

Comment: The `if (!$result) {` should be `if (!$stmt) {`

Comment: Thank you again. I appreciate all of your help. I tried this but got exactly the same error message. Note that execution terminates inside the last `if` block, which suggests to me that `$result` has a value that is assigned in the query, but that the dataset returned is empty (i.e. has 0 records).